# Get min and max value in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have an array like this:

```
array (0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110209172713',
    'Date' => '2011-02-09',
    'Weight' => '200',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110209172747',
    'Date' => '2011-02-09',
    'Weight' => '180',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110209172827',
    'Date' => '2011-02-09',
    'Weight' => '175',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110211204433',
    'Date' => '2011-02-11',
    'Weight' => '195',
  ),
)
```

I need to extract minimal and maximal Weight values. 
In this example

$min_value = 175

$max_value = 200

Any help on how to do this ?
Thank you !

Comment: I'm starting to think that PHP needs a new positional operator with all the recent questions regarding "direct" access to 2-dimensional array indexes...

Comment: `array_pluck` and `array_column` have been suggested (like 7 years ago). I'm not expecting anything similar soon. [And another one here.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

**Option 1.** First you map the array to get those numbers (and not the full details):

```
$numbers = array_column($array, 'weight')
```

Then you get the min and max:

```
$min = min($numbers);
$max = max($numbers);
```

**Option 2.** (Only if you don't have PHP 5.5 or better) The same as option 1, but to pluck the values, use `array_map`:

```
$numbers = array_map(function($details) {
  return $details['Weight'];
}, $array);
```

<strike>Option 3.</strike>

**Option 4.** If you only need a min OR max, `array_reduce()` might be faster:

```
$min = array_reduce($array, function($min, $details) {
  return min($min, $details['weight']);
}, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

This does more `min()`s, but they're very fast. The `PHP_INT_MAX` is to start with a high, and get lower and lower. You could do the same for `$max`, but you'd start at `0`, or `-PHP_INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 16):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $tArray[$k] = $v['Weight'];
}
$min_value = min($tArray);
$max_value = max($tArray);
```

Answer (score 12):

For the people using PHP 5.5+ this can be done a lot easier with [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). Not need for those ugly array_maps anymore.

How to get a max value:

```
$highest_weight = max(array_column($details, 'Weight'));
```

How to get the min value

```
$lowest_weight = min(array_column($details, 'Weight'));
```

Answer (score 8):

It is interesting to note that both the solutions above use extra storage in form of arrays (first one two of them and second one uses one array) and then you find min and max using "extra storage" array. While that may be acceptable in real programming world (who gives a two bit about "extra" storage?) it would have got you a "C" in programming 101.

The problem of finding min and max can easily be solved with just two extra memory slots

```
$first = intval($input[0]['Weight']);
$min = $first ;
$max = $first ;

foreach($input as $data) {
    $weight = intval($data['Weight']);

    if($weight <= $min ) {
        $min =  $weight ;
    }

    if($weight > $max ) {
        $max =  $weight ;
    }

}

echo " min = $min and max = $max \n " ;
```

Comment: You might want to replace `if($weight > $max ) {` by `if($weight >= $max ) {` to ensure that `$max` will always have a `$weight`.

Answer (score 3):

How about without using predefined functions like `min` or `max` ?

```
    //find max 
     $arr = [4,5,6,1];
        $val = $arr[0];
        $n = count($arr);
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
        if($val < $arr[$i]) {
            $val = $arr[$i];
        }
        }
        echo $val;


     //find min 
     $arr = [4,5,6,1];
        $val = $arr[0];
        $n = count($arr);
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
        if($val > $arr[$i]) {
            $val = $arr[$i];
        }
        }
        echo $val;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = array (0 => array ('id' => '20110209172713', 'Date' => '2011-02-09', 'Weight' => '200'),
          1 => array ('id' => '20110209172747', 'Date' => '2011-02-09', 'Weight' => '180'),
          2 => array ('id' => '20110209172827', 'Date' => '2011-02-09', 'Weight' => '175'),
          3 => array ('id' => '20110211204433', 'Date' => '2011-02-11', 'Weight' => '195'));

    foreach($num as $key => $val)   
    {                       
        $weight[] = $val['Weight'];
    }

     echo max($weight);
     echo min($weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = array (0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110209172713',
    'Date' => '2011-02-09',
    'Weight' => '200',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110209172747',
    'Date' => '2011-02-09',
    'Weight' => '180',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110209172827',
    'Date' => '2011-02-09',
    'Weight' => '175',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20110211204433',
    'Date' => '2011-02-11',
    'Weight' => '195',
  ),
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $result[$key] = $value['Weight'];
}
$min = min($result);
$max = max($result);

echo " The array in Minnumum number :".$min."<br/>";
echo " The array in Maximum  number :".$max."<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Location_Category_array = array(5,50,7,6,1,7,7,30,50,50,50,40,50,9,9,11,2,2,2,2,2,11,21,21,1,12,1,5);

asort($Location_Category_array);
$count=array_count_values($Location_Category_array);//Counts the values in the array, returns associatve array
        print_r($count);
        $maxsize = 0;
        $maxvalue = 0;
        foreach($count as $a=>$y){
            echo "<br/>".$a."=".$y;
            if($y>=$maxvalue){
                $maxvalue = $y;
                if($a>$maxsize){
                    $maxsize = $a;
                }
            }
        }

    echo "<br/>max = ".$maxsize;
```

Comment: This does not represent the asker's multidimensional data.

Answer (score 0):

print fast five maximum and minimum number from array without use of sorting array in php
:-

```
<?php  

$array = explode(',',"78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 81, 76, 73,  
68, 72, 73, 75, 65, 74, 63, 67, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73");  
$t=0;  
$l=count($array);  
foreach($array as $v)  
{  
 $t += $v;  
}  
 $avg= $t/$l;  
 echo "average Temperature is : ".$avg."  ";   


echo "<br>List of seven highest temperatsures :-"; 
$m[0]= max($array); 
for($i=1; $i <7 ; $i++)
{ 
$m[$i]=max(array_diff($array,$m));
}
foreach ($m as $key => $value) {
    echo "  ".$value; 
}
echo "<br> List of seven lowest temperatures : ";
$mi[0]= min($array); 
for($i=1; $i <7 ; $i++)
{ 
$mi[$i]=min(array_diff($array,$mi));
}

foreach ($mi as $key => $value) {
    echo "  ".$value; 
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not represent the asker's multidimensional data.