# Arrays in php, accessing another arrays value from array dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array already existing. Lets say it has 3 items.

```
$user = array('people' => 5, 'friends' => 10, 'siblings' => 7);
```

I can then access this array like,

```
echo $user['people']; // 5
echo $user['friends']; // 10
```

Now lets say I have another array called `$person` like,

```
array(3) { 
           [0]=> array(2) 
         { [0]=> string(4) "people" [1]=> string(1) "30" } 
           [1]=> array(2) 
         { [0]=> string(6) "friends" [1]=> string(1) "22" } 
           [2]=> array(2) 
         { [0]=> string(10) "siblings" [1]=> string(1) "71" }
         }
```

I can access my `$user` array by using the second array `$person` manually by doing.

```
 echo $user[$person[0][0]]; // Is accessing $user['people'], 5
 echo $user[$person[0][1]]; // Is accessing $user['friends'], 10
 echo $user[$person[0][2]]; // Is accessing $user['siblings'], 7
```

How can I do this dynamically (as the `$person` arrays keys can change)? Let us say to use it in a function like so,

```
max($user[$person[0][0]], $user[$person[0][1]], $user[$person[0][2]]) // 10
```

If this possible?

Comment: Is `echo $user[$person[0][3]];` really printing content of `$user['siblings']` ? I think it should be `echo $user[$person[0][2]];`

Comment: Ooops my bad!? Just a typo lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [`foreach()`](http://id2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
foreach($person as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value[$key];
}
```

Comment: And how would I go about dynamically adding it to the max function, that is where I am stuck at. The array `$person` could have as many keys as 100.

Comment: @cgwebprojects The `max()` function takes either a set of arguments or one array argument - so you would just build a temporary array and pass that to `max()`

Comment: @cgwebprojects: you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846156/get-min-and-max-value-in-php-array

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution than a `foreach` hard-coded for a two-dimensional array would be PHP's built-in [`RecursiveArrayIterator`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivearrayiterator.getchildren.php):

```
$users = array(
  array('people' => 5, 'friends' => 10, 'siblings' => 7),
  array('people' => 6, 'friends' => 11, 'siblings' => 8),
  array('people' => 7, 'friends' => 12, 'siblings' => 9)
);

$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($users);

while ($iterator->valid()) {
  if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
    // print all children
    foreach ($iterator->getChildren() as $key => $value) {
      echo $key . ' : ' . $value . "\n";
    }
  } else {
    echo "No children.\n";
  }
  $iterator->next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a foreach loop with $user[$person[0]] as the array parameter. If you want to go through both levels of the multidimensional array, you can nest a foreach inside of another foreach