# How can I print the value of the lowest key of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a short question:

This is my array:

```
Array ( [1] => 03 [2] => 02 )
```

I want to print the value of the lowest key. This is my code:

```
$result = min(array_keys($myarray));
```

This prints:

1

But what I need is the value. So the result I want is

03

I tried different variations, for example:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

But nothing is working. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get min and max value in PHP Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846156/get-min-and-max-value-in-php-array)

Comment: `$result = $myarray[min(array_keys($myarray))];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myarray = array( 1 => 3, 2 => 2, 3 => 1 );
//Lowest Value
$result = min(array_values($myarray));
var_dump($result);

//Highest Value
$result = max(array_values($myarray));
var_dump($result);

//Answer
var_dump($myarray[min(array_keys($myarray))]);

//Output
int(1)
int(3)
int(3)
```

I thope this helps :)

Comment: yes, I was looking for something like `array_values` but couldn't find it. Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: Except that this answer doesn't do what you actually asked for, it simply returns the lowest value, and you can do that simply using `min($myArray)` without any need to use `array_values()`

Answer (score 2):

```
$_ar[min(array_keys($arr))]
```

Hope this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the lowest key's value, you were on the right track!

$key fetches the min key and then you use it in the array to fetch the value:

```
$key = min(array_keys($myarray));
echo $myarray[$key];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array by key using:

```
Ksort($arr);
```

Then

```
echo $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
$myarray = [15 => 12, 4 => 43, 1 => 45];
$result = $myarray[min(array_keys($myarray))];
echo $result;
```

Proof: https://3v4l.org/okRFY