# Getting the max, min and avg of an array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this

```
array:3 [
    0 => {
        "id": "1"
        "name": "Product 1"
        "price": "123"
    }
    1 => {
        "id": "2"
        "name": "Product 2"
        "price": "23"
    }
    2 => {
        "id": "3"
        "name": "Product 3"
        "price": "234"
    }
]
```

and I'm trying to find the max, min and the avg of the array.
I'm not sure what I should look for or how I should do this

Comment: Should we assume you mean the Max, Min and Avg of the `price` in this array?

Comment: You probably want to start with `array_column`. min and max are trivial after that, by using the functions of the same names, and how to calculate the average of an array of numbers, is something you should be able to easily research on your own.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - sorry forgot to mention that but yes it's for the price

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846156/get-min-and-max-value-in-php-array).

Answer (score 1):

Like pointed out in the comments, you can use [`array_column`](https://php.net/array_column).

```php
<?php

$arr = [
    0 => [
        "id"    => "1",
        "name"  => "Product 1",
        "price" => "123",
    ],
    1 => [
        "id"    => "2",
        "name"  => "Product 2",
        "price" => "23",
    ],
    2 => [
        "id"    => "3",
        "name"  => "Product 3",
        "price" => "234",
    ],
];

$prices = array_column($arr, 'price');
echo "minimum: " . min($prices) . "\n";
echo "maximum: " . max($prices) . "\n";
echo "average: " . (array_sum($prices) / count($arr)) . "\n";
```